# Laravel 5.4.24 throws MethodNotAllowedHttpException during logout of users

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am working on an authentication system in Laravel 5.4.24. I get an error on my browser when trying to logout: *MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php on line 251*.

The logout route in web.php in routes folder is:

```
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
```

The controller stored app/Http/LoginController.php has the following code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

**Updated Question**
The code below is my login.blade.php

```
@extends('main')

@section('title', '| login')

@section('content')
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-6 col-md-offset-3'>
            {!! Form::open() !!}

                {{ Form::label('email', 'Email:') }}
                {{  Form::email('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}

                {{  Form::label('password', 'Password:') }}
                {{  Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control'])  }}

                <br>
                {{  Form::checkbox('remember') }} {{  Form::label('remember', 'Remember Me:') }}

                <br>
                {{  Form::submit('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block']) }}


            {!!  Form::close()  !!}
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

**main.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- Connection to the partials called _head.blade.php -->
@include('partials._head')
<body>

    @include('partials._nav')

    <!-- The below class container holds all body content-->
    <div class='container'>

        @include('partials._messages')

        {{ Auth::check() ? "Logged In" : "Logged Out"}}

        @yield('content')

        @include('partials._footer')
    </div> <!-- End of container -->

    @include('partials._javascript')
    @yield('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please show how you call the logout link?

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri Since am using localhost and have saved laravel in a directory called sampleBlog: am typing :  localhost/sampleBlog/logout

Comment: @Patwan this url localhost/sampleBlog/logout is get method but in your route define is post method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Route::get('logout', function(){

     return back();

});

Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
```

Comment: Please describe how this answers the question. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.

Answer (score 28):

Just add this line to your *routes/web.php*

`Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout' );`

This fixes it perfectly without having to add any messy code.

Comment: This is the better way if you want to log the user out using get method.

Answer (score 14):

Laravel 5.4+ uses post method for logout so instead of simple url (get) request you should post a form to logout.

In your main.blade.php file replace the following line:

```
{{ Auth::check() ? "Logged In" : "Logged Out"}}
```

with the following example, please change as it fit for your need - it is just example where to put these code.

```
 @if (Auth::guest())
                    <a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>
                @else

                                <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                    onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                             document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                    Logout
                                </a>

                                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                                </form>

                @endif
```

Comment: does this mean I should create another blade file called logout.blade.php cause I can only see login and register blade files in resources/views/auth

Comment: no you should use it as you logout button. where is your logout button! share your html code please

Comment: Oh, I think I have figured out where to post the code and the button finally gets to work. I posted my query wrongly.. Thanks alot Hassan... Thumbs Up !!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a form which I think clutters up the code, what you can do is create a new route named `/logout` and then bind it to the `logout` method in your `Auth` controller.

Jus add this line to your `routes/web.php`

`Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout' );`

Note: I appologise for my code markdown mess-up